# Multiple linear regression for multi-dimensional input and output?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

Assume that I have $N$ points $x_i,i=1,...,N$ in some $A>1$-dimensional  space $\mathbb{R}^A$ with pointwise evaluations of some function $f:\mathbb{R}^A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^B$, i.e. $f(x_i),i=1,...,N$ where $f(x_i) \in \mathbb{R}^B$.

It is my goal to find a multiple linear regression between $x_i$ and $f(x_i)$. Now [sklearn has a function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression) (*sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression*) for a multiple linear regression for functions of the type $f:\mathbb{R}^A \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, but my output is $B$-dimensional. I assume that I could make independent multiple linear regressions for each output dimension and then combine the results, but there must be an easier way of achieving this.

Do you know of a more efficient way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking about multioutput regression. The class you talked about sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression supports this out of the box.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# features
A = 10
# number of values to predict
B = 15
# number of rows in dataset
m = 100

x = np.ones((m, A))
y = np.ones((m, B))

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x, y)
```

sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression actually just creates B models. However it optimises calculations using vectorisation.

It actually is exactly the same as a fully connected layer in a neural network which has no activation function.

You can read more about it here:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-output-regression-models-with-python/

Comment: Well now I feel dumb - I tried doing this before but couldn't get it to work, I must have made some mistake. This is drastically faster than the for-loop solution I have created as a workaround, particularly for large $B$. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can speedup the process using model.fit(x, y, n_jobs=-1). Normally model.fit uses only one the cores from your cpu. If you set n_jobs=-1 it will create as many processes as you have cores and speed up computation.

Comment: Oh, in-built parallelization? Awesome, thanks for the tip!